# IconButton with gradient overlay breaks when tapped

Tags: flutter, icons, flutter-layout

I have an `IconButton` with a gradient overlay, like this

```
Container(
    foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.orange.shade100, Colors.orange.shade900], 
            begin: Alignment(0, 0), 
            end: Alignment(0, 1)
        ), 
        backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.screen
    ),
    child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_box),
        iconSize: 36,
        color: Colors.black,
        onPressed: (){},
    ),
);
```

[image]

It looks great until I tap it, then suddenly the gradient covers the entire `Container` (and the `IconButton`) and stays there.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent it from breaking when tapping it?

Comment: It doesn't cover the entire container for me, can you attach screenshots to show what you are seeing?

Comment: @F-1 Added screenshots of before and after tapping the IconButton.

Comment: that's not what happens for me, using your code. What version of Flutter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It may be an option for you to wrap your Icon in the Container, instead of wrapping the whole IconButton.

```
      IconButton(
        icon: Container(
          foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.orange.shade100, Colors.orange.shade900],
                begin: Alignment(0, 0),
                end: Alignment(0, 1),
              ),
              backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.screen),
          child: Icon(Icons.add_box),
        ),
        iconSize: 36,
        color: Colors.black,
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
```